# MathJax not rendering LaTeX in React with ReactMarkdown

Tags: reactjs, mathjax, react-markdown

I'm currently facing an issue with MathJax and ReactMarkdown in my React application. I've set up a component that uses better-react-mathjax to render Markdown content, including LaTeX math expressions. However, I'm encountering difficulties as only the Markdown content is being rendered, and the LaTeX expressions are not processed by MathJax.

```
export const ContentDetails = ({ content }) => {

  const config = {
    loader: { load: ["[tex]/html"] },
    tex: {
      packages: { "[+]": ["html"] },
      inlineMath: [["$", "$"]],
      displayMath: [["$$", "$$"]]
    }
  };

  const ConvertToHtml = ({ markdownContent }) => {
    return (
      <MathJaxContext config={config} version={3}>
        <MathJax>
          <ReactMarkdown>
            {markdownContent}
          </ReactMarkdown>
        </MathJax>
      </MathJaxContext>
    )

  }

  return (

    <div className='pt-[80px] mb-[80px]'>
      <div className='ml-[60px] mr-[60px] space-y-8'>
        {content?.map((contentItem, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className='mr-[140px] ml-[140px] space-y-6 font-amiri text-right flex flex-col items-end'
          >
            <h1 className='mr-[12px] text-h3'>{contentItem.title}</h1>
            <div className='mr-[12px] text-h6 leading-10 text-[#464848]'>
              <ConvertToHtml markdownContent={contentItem.content_body} />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have already tested that both Mathjax and Reactmarkdown work fine when separate. The issue only raises when I combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`better-react-mathjax` is not adapted to being used together with `react-markdown` and vice versa so it is expected that it requires some fiddling to make it work. MathJax itself works by typesetting the DOM and `better-react-mathjax` leverages this functionality for use with React (which manipulates the DOM in a very particular way). `react-markdown` also manipulates content and the DOM to render markdown correctly and if the resulting format is not in a regular DOM representation with the MathJax delimiters preserved, MathJax will not be able to help you out. There may also be a race condition between the processing of math and the processing of markdown whereby one of the two gets invalidated by the other.

A thorough and controlled solution would thereby involve hooking into the `react-markdown` rendering process and maybe add some wrapper (`MathJax` component or similar). Initially, one can also of course just attempt to wrap the entire `Markdown` component in a `MathJax` component to see if it works.

It turns out that my initial attempts work well after just wrapping the `Markdown` component in a `MathJax` component, so if this doesn't work for you, what happens? Can you create a sandbox where the problem is shown? As I said, I would, if the problem can't be solved, try to hook into the `react-markdown` rendering process and try to add the `MathJax` functionality there, either by means of a `MathJax` component or extract the `MathJaxBaseContext` and then manually typeset with it, although such complicated use should probably not be necessary here.

Here is a sandbox where it works out well: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/user-example-so77769966-q352j2

PS! It seems you're including the `MathJaxContext` in something that looks like a reusable component, the `MathJaxContext` should only exist ONCE in an app and should wrap the entire app (https://github.com/fast-reflexes/better-react-mathjax?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) DS

Comment: Moving the `MathJaxContext` to wrap the whole app and be called only once has solved the issue. Your explanation was very helpful. Thank you sir!